# cURL Inside Vagrant can't connect using invalid SSL

Tags: php, ssl, curl, guzzle

So, I am testing HTTPS calls inside the Vagrant machine and I don't really have luck with connecting to the local server inside the Vagrant, using invalid or self signed HTTPS certificate.  Here's the thing, I can actually connect using curl from my windows box using git bash:

```
curl -k https://example.com
---works---
```

However, making exactly the same call inside the Vagrant machine I get:

```
curl: (35) SSL connect error
```

As you can see, I'm using -k option to ignore insecure SSL, and this really works when I run this on Windows, without it won't work.  Also, I can ping `example.com` from the machine without the problems and even connect to http, and https is the only thing that doesn't work. This is really a problem for me because I'm trying to test Guzzle PHP framework that uses curl to connect to the same server, but this error pops up all the time even though I used `verify=>false`.
Curl version:

```
curl --version
curl 7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.16.2.3 Basic ECC zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2
Protocols: tftp ftp telnet dict ldap ldaps http file https ftps scp sftp
Features: GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM SSL libz
```

Anybody knows the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I just had to use `--tlsv1.2`:

```
curl --tlsv1.2 -k https://example.com
```